# React useEffect with WebSocket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, react-hook

Всем привет,есть компонент на котором отображается график пульса юзера в реал-тайме.
При открытии компонента я открываю соединение с сокетом и записываю последние сообщения от сокета в
состояние и эти данные отображаются на графике,когда страница закрывается мы должны разорвать соединение с сокетом.

Основная логика работала хорошо без useEffect,но что бы сокет открывался и закрывался по состоянию компонента я добавил хук и теперь у меня возникли проблемы с записью данных в стейт

Сокет открывается только при обновлении страницы,и когда данные приходят в компонент графика обновляется каждый раз когда записывает новые значения,место того что бы просто добавить точку без лишних рендеров и отобразить.

[Видео с демонстрацией](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccuu5LHUEGs&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE)

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import {LineChart,Line,XAxis,YAxis,Label,ResponsiveContainer,Tooltip,} from "recharts";
    import Title from "./TittleNav";
    
    //link for connect to socket
    let ws = new WebSocket("wss://elepsio.herokuapp.com/");

    export default function Chart() {
      const theme = useTheme();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        ws.onopen = () => console.log("ws opened");
        ws.onclose = () => console.log("ws closed");
    
        return () => {
          ws.close();
        };
      }, []);
    
      const [barData, setBarData] = useState({
        data: [
          {
            time: "18:02",
            pulse: 87,
          },
        ],
      });
      //set new message to state
        ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        setBarData({ data: [...barData.data, JSON.parse(event.data)] });
      };
      console.log(barData);
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Title>График</Title>
          <ResponsiveContainer>
            <LineChart
              data={barData.data}
              margin={{
                top: 16,
                right: 16,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 24,
              }}
            >
              <XAxis dataKey="time" stroke={theme.palette.text.secondary} />
              <YAxis stroke={theme.palette.text.secondary}>
                <Label
                  angle={270}
                  position="left"
                  style={{ textAnchor: "middle", fill: theme.palette.text.primary }}
                >
                  Пульс
                </Label>
              </YAxis>
              <Tooltip />
              <Line
                type="monotone"
                dataKey="pulse"
                stroke={theme.palette.primary.main}
                dot={false}
              />
            </LineChart>
          </ResponsiveContainer>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
useEffect(() => {
    const ws = new WebSocket("wss://elepsio.herokuapp.com/");
    ws.onopen = () => console.log("ws opened");
    ws.onclose = () => console.log("ws closed");
    ws.onmessage = event=>{
        setBarData({ data: [...barData.data, JSON.parse(event.data)] });
    };
    return () => {
        ws.close();
    };
}, [])
```